# line graph Tickmarks and grid vertical lines are not aligned?

Tags: rgraph

Okay. i have this problem in line graph. Tickmarks(data-points) are not aligned with vertical grid lines. is there a way to achieve that.please help?

[image: sample of line graph]

Answer (score 0):

you number of tick marks need to match the number of vlines. What I often do is I will get the count of my labels variable (with javascript) and so something like this.

```
 var numTicks = labelVariable.length;
```

Then on draw of the graph

```
 options: {
      numxticks: num_ticks
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var xticks = 10;
```

or with php

```
var xticks = "<php echo $yourvariable ;?>";

var line  = .......
.set('chart.numxticks',xticks)
```